# Copying values from one workbook into another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

so I am trying to copy a value from one workbook into another, and keep getting syntax compilation errors. If anyone knows why it would be very helpful

```
Sub findsomething()
Dim rng As Range
Dim account As String
Dim rownumber As Long
Dim dehyp As Long

dehyp = Replace(Range("A5").Value, "-", "")
account = Sheet.Cells(dehyp)


Set rng = sheet1.List-of-substances-in-the-third-phase-of-CMP-(2016- 
2021).xlsx.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=account,
LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
rownumber = rng.Row
Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheet1.List-of-substances-in-the-third- 
phase-of-CMP-(2016-2021).xlsx.Cells(rownumber, 
3).Value

End Sub
```

Cell A5 contains

numbers with hypens such as 279-01-2.
but to be searchable in the other document needs to be in the form of 279012

Comment: What is `List-of-substances-in-the-third- 
phase-of-CMP-(2016-2021).xlsx` ?  Is it an open workbook?

Comment: Yes, it is open at the same time, or I could add this to open it Workbooks.Open ("L:\PRS\CEPA\Chemicals Management Plan\!Overviews and Summaries\List-of-substances-in-the-third-phase-of-CMP-(2016-2021).xlsx")

Comment: Then it's `Workbooks("List-of-substances-in-the-third- 
phase-of-CMP-(2016-2021).xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: Please show us what cell `A5` contains.

Comment: `.Cells(i,j)` should be used with two integer arguments for the row and column number and `.Range(addr)` should be used with a single string argument for the address. I don't think `account = Sheet.Cells(dehyp)` can be correct.

Comment: If `A5` contains the account numbers then you should write `account = Replace(Range("A5").Value, "-", "")` and get  rid if the `Sheet.Cells(dehyp)` call that does something not specified in the post.

Comment: @ja72 yeah you are right, I just didn't know if it would be stored that way thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your code is unclear, but it would be something more like:

```
Sub findsomething()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim account As String
    Dim rownumber As Long
    Dim dehyp As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook

    dehyp = Replace(Range("A5").Value, "-", "") '<< be more specific here about workbook/sheet
    account = Sheet.Cells(dehyp)  '<< and here

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open( _
      "L:\PRS\CEPA\Chemicals Management Plan\!Overviews and Summaries\" & _
      "List-of-substances-in-the-third-phase-of-CMP-(2016-2021).xlsx")

    Set rng = wb.Sheets("sheet1").Columns(1).Find(What:=account, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If not rng is nothing then
        thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value = _
               wb.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(rng.Row, 3).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

This would be tidier as a `Vlookup` though.

Comment: Vloopup assumes values are sorted. They might be not.

Comment: @Tim Williams I took ja72's comment and reformatted the account stuff, but I am getting a end with, without error, any idea why?

Comment: I found out just needed to change the End with to an End if statement and it worked

Comment: @ja72  -that's not always the case - you can use `False` as the last argument.

Comment: @TimWilliams - learn something new I guess. I've always used `Match()` and `Index()` which I think requires sorted data.

Comment: @ja72 - Match, like Vlookup, works fine with unsorted data as long as you pass 0 as the final argument.  The big advantage of index/match over vlookup is that with index/match your lookup column doesn't need to be to the left of your returned value column.